# Building dynamic linq query with checking null for collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function who generate the lambda expression like this

```
d => d.Defendeurs.Any(DossierTiers => DossierTiers.Tiers.TiersLiesEnfantsActifs.Any(TiersLie => TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale.Adresse.CodePostal.Contains("45")))
```

All work but sometimes I got NullExceptionReference on some class.
So I need to check if some property is null.
I think, I must add some code in the BuildLambda function, but all my test doesn't work.
Some help are welcome

```
       public static Expression GetExpression(Expression parameter, object Operator, object value, params string[] properties)
        {
            Expression resultExpression = null;
            Expression childParameter, navigationPropertyPredicate;
            Type childType = null;

            if (properties.Count() > 1)
            {
                parameter = Expression.Property(parameter, properties[0]);
                var isCollection = typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(parameter.Type);
                if (isCollection)
                {
                    childType = parameter.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    childParameter = Expression.Parameter(childType, childType.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    childParameter = parameter;
                }
                var innerProperties = properties.Skip(1).ToArray();
                navigationPropertyPredicate = GetExpression(childParameter, Operator, value, innerProperties);
                if (isCollection)
                {
                    var anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
                    anyMethod = anyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(childType);
                    navigationPropertyPredicate = Expression.Call(anyMethod, parameter, navigationPropertyPredicate);
                    resultExpression = BuildLambda(parameter, navigationPropertyPredicate);
                }
                else
                {
                    resultExpression = navigationPropertyPredicate;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ConstantExpression right = null;
                var childProperty = parameter.Type.GetProperty(properties[0]);
                var left = Expression.Property(parameter, childProperty);
                right = (value != null) ? right = Expression.Constant(value, value.GetType()) : Expression.Constant(string.Empty);
                navigationPropertyPredicate = GetExpression(left, right, Operator);
                resultExpression = BuildLambda(parameter, navigationPropertyPredicate);
            }
            return resultExpression;
        }

        private static Expression BuildLambda(Expression parameter, Expression predicate)
        {
            var resultParameterVisitor = new ParameterVisitor();
            resultParameterVisitor.Visit(parameter);
            var resultParameter = resultParameterVisitor.Parameter;
            return Expression.Lambda(predicate, (ParameterExpression)resultParameter);
        }

       private static Expression GetExpression(MemberExpression left, ConstantExpression right, Object p)
        {
            MethodInfo c = null;
            if (p is OperatorUsedWithString)
            {
                switch ((OperatorUsedWithString)p)
                {
                    case OperatorUsedWithString.CommencePar:
                        c = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
                        return Expression.Call(left, c, right);
                    case OperatorUsedWithString.Contient:
                        c = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
                        return Expression.Call(left, c, right);
                    case OperatorUsedWithString.TerminePar:
                        c = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
                        return Expression.Call(left, c, right);
                    case OperatorUsedWithString.Egal:
                        c = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
                        return Expression.Call(left, c, right);

                }
            }
            if (p is OperatorUsedWithNumber)
            {
                switch ((OperatorUsedWithNumber)p)
                {
                    case OperatorUsedWithNumber.Egal:
                        return Expression.Equal(left, right);
                    case OperatorUsedWithNumber.Inferieur:
                        return Expression.LessThan(left, right);
                    case OperatorUsedWithNumber.InferieurEgal:
                        return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(left, right);
                    case OperatorUsedWithNumber.Superieur:
                        return Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);
                    case OperatorUsedWithNumber.SuperieurEgal:
                        return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(left, right);



                }
            }
            if (p is OperatorUsedWithDateTime)
            {
                switch ((OperatorUsedWithDateTime)p)
                {
                    case OperatorUsedWithDateTime.PasPresent:
                        return Expression.Equal(left, Expression.Constant(null));
                    case OperatorUsedWithDateTime.Present:
                        return Expression.NotEqual(left, Expression.Constant(null));
                }


            }
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you execute it and visual studio halts at the exception, move you mouse pointer of the expression. You should be able to see which part of the expression is NULL. That's how I usually find the bug. If you found it, rule out the part of your data using a where( x => x != null)

Comment: It seems that the exception occured on TiersLie.
And if I add manually the test with null all is ok.
Now how  can I add this on my function ?

Comment: So you mean that it adds "blupp != null &&"  before each "blubb." part of the resulting query?

Comment: So, I want to clarify some things.

Comment: So, I want to clarify some things.
The goal of this function is to generate somes Expression depending on the input parameters. On my database somes class can point to null or point to another class.(So I don't know )
The final is to generate a query to use with a List<object> x.Where(query.Compile()).ToList();  
In all case I think I must check null for all collection or object.
In this case the error occured in TiersLie.TiersEnfant.AdressePrincipale who is null
I don't know if it's clear ? Let me know 
Thank's

Comment: in that case just wrap it in a try catch block with one of the catch statements explicitly checking for null exception. It should be easy to handle then

Comment: @bilpor The problem he has that the generated statement gets the problem with the null exception. And there if even one entry has a null the whole select fails. From what I gather he wants still results then.

Comment: The exact error :
NullReferenceException:
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
at lambda_method( Closure,TiersLie )

Comment: It's possible to make a Expression.AndAlso with a boolean and an Expression ?

Comment: Ok,I found a solution thank's for help